# Launchd plist Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, plist, launchd

So, I'm kinda new to this and have been trying to automate a python to run every 30 seconds but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the plist that I'm running

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.fplautomator</string>

        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/myname/Downloads/Errorfile.txt</string>

        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/myname/Downloads/Errorfile.txt</string>

        <key>ProgramArguments</keys>
        <array>
                <string>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3</string>
                <string>/Users/myname/Documents/Misc\ -\ FPL/Python\ -\ FPL.py</string>
        </array>

        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The error on the console

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.fplautomator[6585]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2
```

With the error message generated from the file being

```
(null): can't open file '/Users/myname/Documents/Misc\ -\ FPL/Python\ -\ FPL.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have searched around and seen a couple of the threads but none of the answers seem to solve the issue for me. The file does work when I run it directly from the terminal and I have chmod 555 the .py file in question as well.

FYI the python file that I'm trying to run is meant to webscrape data using BeautifulSoup into .csv and .json files within the same folder.

Could anyone offer a solution?

Cheers!